# Prevent adding of files in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

Is it possible to prevent other users from adding files to a certain directory?  I tried an exclusive check-out on the folder but that only checks out the separate files within the folder.

Comment: Set the directory permissions so that other users do not have write access.

Comment: I can't see any 'write' access.  Only 'read' access.  There's 'check-in' access but disallowing that is not at all what we want.

Comment: Where are you looking?  Try right clicking on the directory from the Windows Explorer (not from Visual Studio), then select Properties, then select the Security tab.

Comment: Windows Explorer? I don't see how adding permissions on the physical Windows folder on my machine would prevent users from adding a file into TFS.  In fact, default permissions on my machine already prevent other users from having write access.

Comment: You might want to modify your question -- it doesn't say anything about TFS (yes, there's a tag, but you should still include the relevant information in the question itself).  Also you should consider moving this to SuperUser.com

Comment: How does denying checkin access to that folder not meet your needs? About your only alternatives are a custom checkin policy (or forbidden pattern policy) or custom tfs server plugin that watches the checkin event.

Comment: Because that would prevent check-in of existing files, which is quite necessary for our developers to do their jobs.  We only want to prevent them from adding new files without consulting us first.

Comment: Honestly i would expect preventing people from adding files would also be quite necessary for them to do their job. However I stand by my first comment - you probably need a custom checkin policy, plugin or require developers to shelf changes and have someone else check them in.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the folder in TFS Source Control Explorer -> Advanced -> Security...
You can set the Permissions for the folder. I guess you want to set the Check In property to deny - but your question is not crystal clear.